# OnePlus One Not found in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

My problem is that my OnePlus One phone is not found in Eclipse on my Mac even after trying things like activating USB debugging of course and even Menu>Storage>*menu on the upper right corner*>USB computer connection>*check box MTP/PTP*.

When i try adb devices it tells me that there is no device found.

I have tried two different cables (including stock cable).

It seems that with mac there are no drivers to install needed.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Sebastien

Comment: can you try windows or linux? it works here in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer Jiang YD.

Finally, i have tried again with the same conditions few days later and Android file transfer recognized my OPO.
My OPO activated the Debug Mode automatically.
And the best is that Eclipse recognize my OPO for debugging.

So everything works well but i don't really undestand why it didn't worked the first time.

It works with the stock cable.